# how to move next and previous html files inside folder without putting their path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have several html files inside folders, example

folder 1 - has a 45 html files (01.html, 02.html.....)
folder 2 - has a 43 html files (01.html, 02.html.....)
and e.t

now i want inside html without putting their path its automatically find next or previous html files. example if 01.html, then clicking next button will automarically find 02.html inside same folder.

i dont want like this

```
<div class="navigation"><a href="01.html"class="previous"><img src="../images2/previous.png" /></a><a href="../index.html"><img src="../images2/icon-home.png"/></a><a href="03.html"class="next"><img src="../images2/next.png" /></a></div>
```

i want something like this:

```
<div class="navigation"><a href="**previousfile**"class="previous"><img src="../images2/previous.png" /></a><a href="../index.html"><img src="../images2/icon-home.png"/></a><a href="**nextfiles**.html"class="next"><img src="../images2/next.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: you have 45 individually numbered HTML files? Unless they're all completely unique and designed differently, are you sure you don't need some sort of templating engine and database instead of physically separate files?

Comment: Please post code that you  have tried so we may assist.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont have code, all what i have i posted

Comment: When you click on Prev or Next, does the page refresh or are they AJAX calls? If the page refreshes, than what you mentioned as "don't want like this", is the approach to take.

Comment: ok, thanks. i dont have ajax calls